# Will stopping my query rollback all my queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have started a Query like the following in SQL Mgt studio:

[image]

Currently running sp_who I can see the Query is running for `TBCompany_503`

My question is that if I Kill the process for `TBCompany_503` will it rollback the changes for `TBCompany_500` - `TBCompany_502` ?

Reason I want to stop it, and run them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you wrapped those calls in the same transaction, otherwise those previously ran updates are committed already.

Comment: I haven't added any transactions, the script is as above in the image. so Every line is one update - ending eith a semi-colon

Comment: @DawoodAwan Right, so then the previous updates are already committed as they finish running (and only each update statement that hasn't finished executing yet will get rolled back).

Comment: Thanks - now I can Kill the process without worrying my changes will get reverted

Comment: Why don't you use `begin tran` / `rollback tran`?